# Why does the for loop output this?

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

I am just very confused from this homework problem. I do not understand why the values of **i** and **sum** come out this way. I just do not understand the concept of the algorithm here, can someone please explain this?

```
int i = 0;
int sum = 0;
for(i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    sum += i;
}
System.out.println(i + "\n" + sum);
```

The output is:

```
5
10

----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: What part do you not understand here?

Comment: Print out the values of i and sum inside the loop and see how they change.

Comment: 0+1+1+1+1+1 = 5 = `i`.  0+0+1+2+3+4 = 10 = `sum`.

Comment: I know java, I just could not get my head to comprehend the simple stuff

Comment: Time to close this question before rating depreciates more

Answer (score 6):

- 5 - because there are 5 iterations
- 10 - because the sum is 10 :)

Sum

```
Iteration 1: 0 + 0 = 0
Iteration 2: 0 + 1 = 1
Iteration 3: 1 + 2 = 3
Iteration 4: 3 + 3 = 6
Iteration 5: 6 + 4 = 10
```

Verification code

```
int i = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format(
        "Iteration %s: %s + %s = %s", (i + 1), sum, i, (sum + i)));
    sum += i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code :

```
  int i = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  for(i=0; i < 5; i++)
  {
     sum += i;
  }
  System.out.println(i + "\n" + sum);
```

output in `sum` this : 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 which is equal to 10 and `i` the number of iterations = 5.

Answer (score 3):

You have created a variable `i` with value of `0` and then incrementing it 5 times in for-loop. So you got `i`'s value as `5`.

Now the value of sum is `0+1+2+3+4` which is `10`

Answer (score 1):

Because you iterate through your loop, which makes i == 5, then print it,

Sum goes as below, you are adding i to the previously calculated sum

```
0 + 1 = 1 
1 + 2 = 3
3 + 3 + 6
6 + 4 = 10
```

Try put your print command inside the loop, they you can see better what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The only non-obvious thing is (in my opinion): `i` will be 5, because you used `i++`, which also incremented `i` by 1 even though the body did not execute after the last iteration. Inside the body `i` only can be maximum 4.

```
int sum = 0; int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    sum += i;
    if (i == 5)
        System.out.println("never executed");
};
```

Other answers tell the other things.